# Possible bug with badges

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Yesterday, I attempted to earn the Vox Populi badge. At the time, I had 9 badges. Even though I used the maximum 40 votes for that day, I somehow failed to earn the badge. Today, I logged in and tried for Vox Populi again. I got the badge this time, but my badge count rose to 11....?

[image]

Thinking this was odd, I went to my profile, and clicked the gear in BADGES. I then selected all, and at the top was all the badges i had collected so far.
Sure enough.....

[image: Only 10 badges here!]

.....there was only 10 badges that I have earned.

I thought it might be fixed if I waited for a while, but the "phantom" badge remains. I think that the badge somehow counted double due to me meeting the requirements to obtain the badge yesterday, but that is just my guess.

**Edit: The suffrage badge was part of the 9 badges I had yesterday.**

Comment: According to your [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5221707/human-bat?tab=badges&sort=recent) you have 11 bronze badges, so the count is correct. Perhaps you are just confused since the Tumbleweed badge does not appear in that badge tracker there?

Comment: You had 10 bronze badges yesterday when you earned Suffrage, Vox Populi was badge #11.  The progress tracker for badges doesn't include badges for which there is no progress to track (like Tumbleweed) and shouldn't be seen as a complete record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that I thought I had 1 extra badge was due to the progress tracker not listing the badge tumbleweed. Thank you all for your explanations! Closed.